# oracle dropped table is still there

Tags: oracle, plsql

i created a table as select.
column A, column B, column C
i then dropped it, even with purge command.
i added a Column B2
column A, column B, column B2, column C
and ran the Create table as Select command.
when i query Select * from newtable i get

column A, column B, column C, Column B2
How come and why?  Why isn't Column B2 in the place I created it, between B & C.  This is a headache since I really have a table with 75 columns and I want to view the data near the front. Thank you.

```
create table NewTable1 nologging parallel 8 compress as 
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC from table;

DROP TABLE NewTable1  PURGE;

create table NewTable1 nologging parallel 8 compress as 
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColB2, ColC from table;
```

Comment: Post your create / drop statements and table definition how you are creating new table

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour even when deleting the table without a PURGE.

Comment: I believe it @BriteSponge, its so weird. I've never seen this before. I feel like I am going crazy with this.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted the table from the right schema? You can always specify the schema name if you want to be 100% sure.

Comment: The alternative of course is not to worry about the table at all but just create a view to show the columns in the order that suits you best.

Comment: I agree that the DB is not where I should be showing column order, it was just a quick project on DB development side and i had never seen this before and it seemed weird to me, so i thought i'd ask and see if i am dropping a table incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add another column for my project, so i dropped/purge again, but this time i noticed i am in SQL DEVELOPER and the CTAS is in one tab and the drop statement is in another tab. they both use the schema name in front of the table, but this time when i did DROP & CTAS from same tab in SQL Developer, then i queried from another tab, all columns were in correct order. So?? maybe its a sql developer or session issue?

Answer (score 0):

Table DDL and your CTAS query would make it easier for us to help you.

But you might take a look at all_tab_columns for your table.  That view has column COLUMN_ID in it and it is that column which determines how your columns appear when you query a table without specifying column order.  It is the order in which the columns where specified when you created the table.

So unless you specify the column order, your new table will have the columns in the order in which they exist in the original table.

By way of example:

```
    CREATE TABLE qazz
    (
     a      NUMBER
    ,b      NUMBER
    ,c      NUMBER
    ,b2     DATE
    );

CREATE TABLE qazz_2 AS SELECT * FROM qazz;

CREATE TABLE qazz_3 AS SELECT a, b, b2, c FROM qazz;

SELECT table_name, column_name, column_id 
    FROM all_tab_columns 
    WHERE table_name LIKE 'QAZZ%' 
    ORDER BY table_name, column_id;
```

Comment: you said:  "So unless you specify the column order, your new table will have the columns in the order in which they exist in the original table."  But if i drop the original table i created and purge, and then create table as select again with same name, wouldn't it create it with the order i specified instead of tacking the new columns on at the end?

Comment: create table NewTable1 nologging parallel 8 compress as 
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC from table;

then I drop the table:
DROP TABLE NewTable1  PURGE;

create table NewTable1 nologging parallel 8 compress as 
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColB2, ColC from table;

Comment: The OP did not add a column to an existing table. He **dropped** the table and then recreated it. `?_TAB_COLUMNS` should have no "memory" - when the table is re-created (with its old name) and some of the columns have the same names as before, `?_TAB_COLUMNS` shouldn't even "remember" that a table by the same name existed before it was dropped.

Comment: I had to add another column for my project, so i dropped/purge again, but this time i noticed i am in SQLDEVELOPER and the CTAS is in one tab and the drop statement is in another tab.  they both use the schema name in front of the table, but this time when i did DROP & CTAS from same tab in SQL Developer, then i queried from another tab, all columns were in correct order.  So?? maybe its a sql developer or session issue?

Comment: Most likely not an issue with the tool, but in how the tool was used.